# Как расположить два тега <hr> на одном уровне?

Tags: html, css

Нужно чтобы слева и справа были теги `<hr>`, но их постоянно кидает друг под друга.

Как сделать так, чтобы они располагались на одном уровне?

Comment: hr - блочный элемент и занимает всю строку.

Comment: а запихнуть в таблицу/пару дивов?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nbh1ws39/13/
Вот моё предложение, если я правильно понял вопрос.

Comment: @Sevastopol' Согласен, мне так же не понятно. hr уже старый век. Если это элементы декора я бы вешал на псевдо элементы.

Comment: hr - это не старый век. Это нормальный элемент с понятной семантикой. Меня всегда пугают верстальщики, которые пытаются его сверстать на дивах.

Answer (score 2):

так?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

hr {
  width: 33%;
  height: 0;
}

.text {
  width: 33%;
  background: pink;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <hr/>
  <div class="text">some text</div>
  <hr/>
</div>
```